Quantitative Finance site design and logo — Draft
As mentioned in our first post – below you'll find the site design we came up with based on your original ideas for the Quantitative Finance Stack Exchange site. After researching and reading through your ideas, we’re excited to share a draft of the new site theme. Thank you for being patient with us.
Color scheme

To generate ideas for colors, we used a site called Picular and obtained interesting results of gold and bronze with the keyword “Finance”.
Header & Logo

The logo is a coin with a candlestick graph, something you may see a lot in this field. Let us know in the comments if we’re completely off-topic. It was somewhat difficult to land on an interesting concept for this community; we hope you like this direction!

If you were physically holding one of these coins, you may notice its other side has the Stack Exchange logo. As seen on the right of the header.
Favicon

Badges

They might look more like currency now, but they’re not for trade!
Page Design

Process
We hope you enjoy this design, but if something doesn’t feel right, now is your chance to share your feedback. This window for feedback will be open for one week. We will then work to incorporate feedback as best as we can, finalize things on our end, and lastly, deliver the design to your site.

The candlestick graph looks too much like something from technical analysis. :( That would be a a definite turn-off. How about a stylized friendly volatility smile instead?  E.g. https://www.investopedia.com/thmb/lgO9sE2B9422_XOT13NbeMD-L5A=/6251x0/filters:no_upscale():max_bytes(150000):strip_icc()/VolatilitySmileDefinitionandUses2-6adfc0b246cf44e2bd5bb0a3f2423a7a.png

@DimitriVulis, noted! Will iterate on that, thank you.

An idea that might be worth investigating: In order to make it more "Quant-finance" what about adding some PDEs in the background of the banner behind the coins to the right (For PDEs, see this answer at "Parabolic PDEs", the first and last equation)? The colour of the PDEs could be on the "light" side to blend more in with the background, but still be visible to the viewer (I don't know if that makes sense).

It makes sense, thank you @Pleb

Or even more than the PDE, just the fundamental equation of asset pricing: 1=E[MR]. Or Pt = E[M_t+1 P_t+1]: see here: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/55239/explaining-the-risk-neutral-measure/55251#55251

Update: Your new site design is live!
